# open multiple images from one thumbnail in custom wordpress gallery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, themes, lightbox

I made a custom gallery option for my theme using Advanced Custom Fields Plugin for WP. It lets the user upload images to a custom page which on clicking opens a lightbox to show the full-sized image. What I want to do now is open a gallery of images using just one thumbnail. The only thumbnail showing on the page will be one that gives the user an idea of what is inside.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do it the conventional way (create a list of thumbnails linked to full-size images and display using something like Fancybox) and hide all but one of the thumbnails (see [Fancybox FAQ](http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-fancybox/faq/)), although that's not good for bandwidth if the gallery is going to have more than a handful of images; or you could use the thumnbail to launch a modal window and pull in the gallery from there. So the thumbnail would open a template file in a modal window like this:

```
<a href="lightbox.php?galleryID=1" rel="fancybox" />
```

Then `lightbox.php` can take the `galleryID` from the URL and create the gallery in whatever style you see fit.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i made a custom jquery script for my theme alongside the Advanced Fields Plugin which let a user upload the images from within the edit pages section. Any ideas on that?

Comment: so the user uploads images using ACF, then they're displayed on the frontend?

Comment: yes, i created custom fields for the user to upload images when they edit the specific pages based on a certain template.those images are then shown on the page and clicking on them brings up a lightbox.i want to open a lightbox to show more images but not add it to the page itself.

Comment: same answer then: open a php file in the lightbox (there are many lightbox jQuery plugins that can do this) and pull in the gallery images using an ID.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit dated, but I had been tearing my hair out looking for the same thing and finally got it figured out. Thought I'd share.

Using [ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com) and the [Easy FancyBox](http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-fancybox) plugin for WordPress, I created the following query (for my purposes I'm using a custom post type, but obviously this would work for any kind of post).

```
<?php
     $my_query = new WP_Query( array( 
         'post_type'        => 'YOUR-CUSTOM-POST-TYPE', 
         'posts_per_page'   => 15, ) ); 
                while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) { 
                    $my_query->the_post();
                    $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($my_query->ID), 'full' );
                    $url = $thumb['0']; 
                    $images = get_field('gallery', $my_query->ID);
?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" rel="gallery-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></a>
                    <div class="fancybox-hidden">
                        <?php if( $images ) {
                                foreach( $images as $image ) { ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" rel="gallery-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" title="<?php echo $image['title']; ?>"/></a>   
                        <?php } } ?>
                    </div>
                
<?php } ?>
```

The auto-gallery feature needs to be disabled under the Easy FancyBox settings (Admin>Media) in order for the rel= to be taken into account. Of course thumb sizes, etc can be modified to suit your needs.

Hope this helps someone else!

cheers,

-jennyb